# Submit form elements as email

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a requirement in which the user should not be able to register to site, but only request registration by filling the form (first name, last name, email, company, etc.). The request should go to site admin's e-mail id. Using [webform](http://www.drupal.org/project/webform) I have created the form, but I am not able to send it as email.

Also the "Per user submission limit" option of webform is decided by the IP address or cookie (for anonymous user), whereas I would like to limit the form submission by the e-mail ids of the submitting users. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to use the information in the webform to make a user account?  What type of "registration" do you mean?

Comment: Yes, the site admin will create the account based on the information in the webform filled by the anonymous users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all due respect, I think Webform is the wrong way to approach this.  Drupal core can be configured to handle registration in the manner you are requesting with less workload for your site admins (no manual registration of webform data).

1. On  `Administration >> Configuration >> People` (admin/config/people/accounts):

   - Set `Who can register accounts?` to `Visitors, but administrator approval is required`
2. As for the fields in the Webform (first name, last name, e-mail, company, etc.), you should create those on the `Administration >> Configuration >> People >> Account settings` page (admin/config/people/accounts/fields) under the `Manage fields` tab.  Make sure to mark the fields as required and to display them on the registration form.  Note that storing these fields as part of the user account will cause all of this information to be displayed in the user profile.  If you need field-level control of the information (to make last name private/hidden, for example), you can use the [Field permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.
3. *edited per Berdir's comment* By default, Drupal will send an e-mail to the site administrator when an account is registered.  If you need a special notification, you can use the core Trigger and Actions modules (or the contributed [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module) to set up an action (or rule) to e-mail the administrator(s) when a new account is registered and pending approval.

Comment: Re 3., Drupal actually does send a mail automatically to the configured site e-mail address. But yes, if you need to notify a different e-mail, you'd need something like Rules.

Comment: @patrick & berdir : Thank you so much for your help! Actually I'm a newbie in Drupal. The reason I decided to use webform is the default validation it provides for e-mail and other fields, but it was making the logic complex. I really appreciate your prompt help :-)

Comment: To add validation to the user fields, you can use the Field Validation module. (http://drupal.org/project/field_validation)